# Fail2ban ban action error on debian

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, fail2ban

I'm not sure where to start looking for the issue here
This is on debian 11 (using nftables)

It seems like the `nft add set ...` command is failing

`nft add set inet f2b-table addr-set-wordpress \{ type ipv4_addr\; \}`

My jail.local

```
[DEFAULT]
# configure nftables
banaction = nftables
chain = input

[sshd]
enabled = true
port = 1984
banaction = nftables[type=multiport]
maxretry = 3
bantime = 600
findtime = 1200

[wordpress]
enabled = true
banaction = nftables[type=multiport]
filter = wordpress
maxretry = 2
bantime = 1h
findtime = 1d
port = http,https
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*access*.log

[modsec]
enabled = true
banaction = nftables[type=multiport]
filter = apache-modsecurity
maxretry = 2
bantime = 1h
findtime = 6h
port = http,https
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error*.log
```

part of my nft ruleset

```
table inet f2b-table {
    chain f2b-chain {
        type filter hook input priority filter - 1; policy accept;
    }
}
```

And the error

````
2023-04-08 12:19:26,582 fail2ban.actions        [73157]: NOTICE  [wordpress] Restore Ban 107.180.77.81
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- exec: nft add table inet f2b-table
nft -- add chain inet f2b-table f2b-chain \{ type filter hook input priority -1 \; \}
nft add set inet f2b-table addr-set-wordpress \{ type ipv4_addr\; \}
for proto in $(echo 'tcp' | sed 's/,/ /g'); do
nft add rule inet f2b-table f2b-chain $proto dport \{ $(echo 'http,https' | sed s/:/-/g) \} ip saddr @addr-set-wordpress reject
done
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: 'Error: Could not process rule: Numerical result out of range'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: 'add set inet f2b-table addr-set-wordpress { type ipv4_addr; }'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: 'Error: No such file or directory'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: 'add rule inet f2b-table f2b-chain tcp dport { http,https } ip saddr @addr-set-wordpress reject'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- stderr: '                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.utils          [73157]: ERROR   7f21bc2b26b0 -- returned 1
2023-04-08 12:19:26,652 fail2ban.actions        [73157]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'wordpress' action 'nftables' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '107.180.77.81', 'family': 'inet4', 'fid': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f21bc8f48b0>, 'raw-ticket': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f21bc8f4f70>})': Error starting action Jail('wordpress')/nftables: 'Script error'
2```
````

Comment: Figured out the problem - the chain name in nftables is limited to 15 characters max length

Answer (score 0):

edit: if the nft table is failling here is what you can try, check if you have the package `sudo apt-get install nftables`, that the directory exist `/etc/nftables/` if not, `sudo mkdir /etc/nftables/`, and give it the proper permission, check for syntax error in `/etc/nftables.conf`

There is a problem with the nftables rules generated by the `Fail2Ban`, fix the port value in your `jail.local` file, fix it like that

```
[wordpress]
...
port = 80,443
...
[modsec]
...
port = 80,443
...
```

then lets modify the `banaction` directive like this

```
[wordpress]
...
banaction = nftables-allports
...

[modsec]
...
banaction = nftables-allports
...
```

you can then restart `Fail2ban` `sudo systemctl restart fail2ban`

Comment: I've updated the question - it's the `nft add set ...` command which is failing.
It also fails if I do this manually.

Comment: I have updated my anwer

Answer (score 0):

This issue is actually caused by a limit in nftables for names for tables, chains and set ... The max length is 15 characters.

So if you have the following section in fail2ban

```
[wordpress]
enabled = true
banaction = nftables[type=multiport]
filter = wordpress
maxretry = 2
bantime = 1h
findtime = 1d
port = http,https
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*access*.log
```

Fail2ban tries to create a set called `addr-set-wordpress` which is > 15 characters. Changing the section name to `[wp]` resolves the issue because the set name is `addr-set-wp`

If think the error message returned by fail2ban needs to be fixed to something helpful.